# Getting response from PHP in jquery $.post or equivalent

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending JQUERY $.post request to my php method, it looks like that:

```
$.post("/controller/method/",{id: cell_id},function(data,status,xhr)
{
         some_javascript_function();
})
```

PHP:

```
public function method()
{
   insert to database code...
}
```

my PHP function just insert a record into table, which some_javascript_function() will use - cause it request data from database. Sometimes my PHP function is too slow to insert record before some_js_function() tries to get it from database.

Hoe can I manage some response from PHP when everything is ready, and then call some_js_function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the read after the write has returned. `$.post` has a callback function, that's when you're guaranteed the write has completed.

Comment: This callback is executed when SENDING via post is completed, I want it to be executed after PHP function is completed.

Comment: @pawel - once PHP completes is when the callback gets executed. Given the fact that the request succeeded. Therefore, what you did in your example is correct. It seems you're not asking the question properly.

Comment: I'm assuming you have no strange assynchronousness on your PHP side. When the `$.post` request completes, PHP is done, it's completed whatever that `$.post` wanted it to do. If your read fails at this point there is some other mistake.

Comment: According to the jQuery documentation, the third parameter is the success callback. So the function you're passing into the $.post is being executed after it executes the server side code. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: @pawel: The callback *is* executed when the PHP function is completed.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is return data from the PHP function after the insertion is done. It would look like below.

```
function store()
{
    //your code......

    //let's assume that store function will do the data storing part.

    $state = store(); // you should return true after the data insertion is successful

    if($state)
     echo $data; // here we echo data to used in the callback function.
}
```

Callback function is executed after the current effect is 100% finished.